# how fix this error AttributeError: 'DegreeView' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 17>()
     15             methods.append('SW_L')
     16     return methods
---> 17 graph_identification()

Input In [12], in graph_identification()
      3 for G in P1_Graphs:
      4     degrees = G.degree()
----> 5     degree_values = sorted(set(degrees.values()))
      6     degree_hist = [list(degrees.values()).count(i) / float(nx.number_of_nodes(G)) for i in degree_values]
      7     clustering = nx.average_clustering(G)

AttributeError: 'DegreeView' object has no attribute 'values'
```

---

```
def graph_identification():
    methods = []
    for G in P1_Graphs:
        degrees = G.degree()
        degree_values = sorted(set(degrees.values()))
        degree_hist = [list(degrees.values()).count(i) / float(nx.number_of_nodes(G)) for i in degree_values]
        clustering = nx.average_clustering(G)
        shortest_path = nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
        
        if len(degree_hist)>10:
            methods.append('PA')
        elif clustering < 0.1:
            methods.append('SW_H')
        else:
            methods.append('SW_L')
    return methods
graph_identification()
```

Comment: correct the indentation, display.  Also explain the source of `P1_Graphs`

Comment: Looking up `DegreeView`, I found this question: https://groups.google.com/g/networkx-discuss/c/4yNifHfCfF8.   I suspect you need to read the `networkx` docs more carefully.  When you get an `attributerror`, you either have the wrong kind of object, or haven't read the docs for your class carefully enough.